# ProgressBar Height issue in Android Version 4.4.2 (Samsung)

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using ProgressBar in my application. And I am also showing value on it.
But Issue is something else here. I am not getting Proper height in `Android Version 4.4.2`

**My Code :**

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int ratio = ((int) display.getWidth() / 100)* value;
    ((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(ratio);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ratio, 35);
    ((ProgressBar) view).setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Progressbar layout.xml:**

```
<ProgressBar
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here, I am setting Width and height of `ProgressBar`. It is working fine in all versions. But Issues on android Version 4.4.2.
***Note:* I have tested it on Emulator and I am getting perfect height in Android Version 4.4.2. Then I tested it on Samsung Galaxy S4 (version 4.4.2), getting issue in this mobile**

Check image below, for same code :
[image: Progress bar]

Comment: What is the issue? can you upload some images?

Comment: What base theme are you using?

Comment: @MarkBuikema, `ProgresBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`

Comment: What theme are you using for you activity in your manifest?

Comment: @MarkBuikema, I am not applying any extra theme, It is default theme : android:Theme.Light